# CLion code completion only for dot/period

Tags: c++, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, clion, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to have code completion only come up when I press the period?

I just want code completion for finding methods and properties of stuff.

Edit: I guess it might be also be helpful to show the settings(in content assist) I want with eclipse options just in case I explained poorly.

[image]

Comment: I do not think it's possible. Plus, why would you want to omit completion for the actual variable/class/constant/etc names and have it enabled for members only... But you can always disable automatic completion popup and invoke it manually only when needed (`Ctrl + Space` by default on most keymaps/OS).

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm doing right now. I don't like having variables names and other things like that popup because say if I have a variable sy, then I get a bunch of stuff like System. popping up and when I use arrow keys to move around my program, it gets stuck. Is there a good alternative to not use arrow keys or mouse for going back to old code?

Comment: *"...and when I use arrow keys to move around my program, it gets stuck."* You should be able to close the popup with hitting the `Esc` button (works for me like that here on Windows; not sure how it will behave if IdeaVim is in use (as I do not use it)).

Comment: *"Is there a good alternative to not use arrow keys or mouse for going back to old code?"* TBH not quite sure what you mean here (what you want to see and where navigate to). But you can use `Navigate | Back / Last Edit Location` or alike -- may help in some cases. P.S. I do not think this is relevant here... but just going to mention this: `Code | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)` can complete any words that you have earlier in the document (before the current caret position).

Comment: Another idea: you can have current file splitt into 2+ parts/tabs and can scroll then independently (so they can show different parts of the file). Right click on the editor tab and look for actions that have "Split" word.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments :). I mainly just need to write code fast for competitive programming and having to press enter or esc or moving to my mouse is annoying because they are far away. Sorry about the confusion, but I used "old code" as in code that I coded above. Thanks for all the other suggestions, and those seem nice for development and the industry.  I guess there just there might not be a solution for clion which sucks but I use to use eclipse and it had an option like that.

Comment: This is the best ticket I could find so far: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7368 (it's for IntelliJ / Java .. but it refers to the same logic as on your screenshot). Other than that I may only suggest these: 1) Check [CLion Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) for similar sort of ticket. 2) If none found -- file your own Feature Request ticket (leave a link back here if you do).